# android location finder from latitude and longitude

Tags: android, location, finder

How can we get address or location name from latitude and longitude in android In my application I have set of latitude and longitude, But I need an API which will return me the location name corresponding to the latitude and longitude.
thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Through [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) we can get the location name according to lattitude and longitude

```
List<Address> addresses = new Geocoder(<CurrentActivityName>.this,Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(cur_lat, cur_lon, 1);

          Address addr= addresses.get(0);

          String Country=addr.getCountryName();
          String  State=addr.getSubAdminArea();
          String  City=addr.getLocality();
```

Comment: hi Praveena i applied this code but there occur an exception of Service not avilable. if you can please tell whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Nice answer, but `getSubAdminArea()` and `getLocality()` returns same as City.

Answer (score 0):

Gps will not work on emulator... u have to test this on device.